# Generate random string WITHOUT time?

Tags: string, go, random

I know how to generate a random string in go using Runes & seeding rand.Init with `time.UnixNano()`. My question is, is it possible (with the stdlib) to seed rand without using the current timestamp (secure)?

Furthermore, I ask because isn't just relying on time to generate a random string for a sensitive operation insecure/a vulnerability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sensitive operations use [`crypto/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/) instead of `math/rand`:

> Package [crypto/] rand implements a cryptographically secure random number generator.

Note that you don't need (you can't) seed `crypto/rand`.

Comment: Yep, thanks. Surprised this question wasn't already asked (at least with the terms I was thinking.)

Comment: `secure/rand` doesn't exist, but your link correctly points to `crypto/rand`.

Comment: @Adrian Ops, typo, fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can seed it with anything, it just takes an integer. Time is commonly used because it changes and there aren't a lot of sources for good random seeds that aren't constant - if you use the same seed, you'll get the same sequence of values, so typically you want something that changes.

Is it insecure? Absolutely! If you need *secure* random number generation, you *must* use `crypto/rand` instead: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/

`crypto/rand` does not offer a way to seed it because it's seeded using the system's cryptographically-strong random number generator.